# using wp_footer hook in a plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, hooks

I'm using the wp_footer hook into the plugin and it doesn't work, but when I copy the code to the "functions.php" file of the active theme it does work, what is the possible problem in this situation ?

```
    function mixpanel_footer(){

echo '<a style="margin-left:45%;" href="https://mixpanel.com/f/partner"><img src="//cdn.mxpnl.com/site_media/images/partner/badge_white.png" alt="Mobile Analytics" /></a>';

     } 
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mixpanel_footer' );
```

Comment: Please post the code you're using so we can have a better idea of what you're trying to do.

Comment: are you hooking the code when you put it into `functions.php`? if not maybe your theme doesn't have `wp_footer` in the `footer.php` Without code that's my first guess.

Comment: I updated the question, Yes I'm pretty sure that the theme has `wp_footer` in `footer.php`, that's why it's working when I put the code in `functions.php`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, remove the `margin-left` CSS property from your html and then try if it works. May be your html is being hidden behind any other html.

Or better try this first -

Remove the current code from your function and just write any non html thing. Then put a `die()` or `exit()` and see if it's being rendered properly. Then you can do further debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding priority to hook as following:

```
function mixpanel_footer(){

echo '<a style="margin-left:45%;" href="https://mixpanel.com/f/partner"><img src="//cdn.mxpnl.com/site_media/images/partner/badge_white.png" alt="Mobile Analytics" /></a>';

 } 
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mixpanel_footer', 5 );
```

For more information on adding priority to wp_footer hook visit [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer).

Comment: I tried it before but it didn't work either.

Comment: Is other functionality of plugin working well?

Comment: I have added this code in the plugin file hello.php of Hello Dolly plugin and it worked well. Is there anything wrong in your plugin code?

Comment: @WaseemAbuSenjer - If you view the source of the page, is the HTML being added? It's possible the hook is echoing properly but is hidden due to styles. Also, try adding a priority higher than 5.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please use this code? I think it will work properly.

```php
function your_function(){
    do_action( 'your_action' );
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'your_function' );
```

Comment: Why would that help? There's no separate action to do in the original code. The original code is a wp_footer handler just like you've written.